# Upload a image in flickr shows error

Tags: android, ioexception, flickr

I am integrating my `android` project with `flickr`,for that I downloaded example code from [this](https://github.com/luminousman/Flickr) link.when I tried to upload image from gallery it shows `IOException` in my `Logcat`.

```
java.io.IOException: Connection Failed. Response Code: 403, Response Message: Forbidden, Error: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rsp stat="fail">    <err code="95" msg="SSL is required" /></rsp>
```

Answer (score 6):

Flickr has converted into ssl and each service has ssl. So use https insted of http from 27 june 2014.
Here is documentation [flicker update](http://code.flickr.net/2014/04/30/flickr-api-going-ssl-only-on-june-27th-2014/)
change the jar of flicker to 2.1.0+

You can download the new jar [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2la81cfyb6yzmae/flickrj-android-2.1.0.jar)

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.flickrj-android/flickrj-android/2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Change your request url to the flickr service from `http:` to `https:`